# Profile node.js application running in aws fargate

Tags: node.js, profiling, aws-fargate

I have a node.js application that runs inside docker in aws ec2 fargate.
It started to consume high cpu, and i wonder if i can profile it

I couldn't find a way to connect via ssh, and I am not sure if it helps to run it with --prof flag

Comment: Did you try using PaperTrail logging? pretty good solution for diagnostic inside your code.

Answer (score 1):

I am a newbie in AWS myself, so please check everything that I will say. EC2 Fargate is provisioning EC2 instances for you and you are not allowed to interact with them directly (ssh) but I think you can use CloudWatch Logs, that prints every **console.log** of your app in the specified log groups. There are must be some configurations when you create your task definition or container defifnition. (at least in Cloudformation which I hardly recommend to use). You can **console.log** the number of users or function calls and use this info to debug what is happening.